# how to sort a dict by format dates values

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting, date, datetime

I got a dict of names as keys and formated dates as values, I managed to have the list of these dates sorted, but I dont know how to now sort my dict with this "custom order", since the dates are weirdly formated, sort() won't work.

Here is an example :

```
dict = {'Charles':'01/02-21:00','Martin':'01/03-22:00','David':'01/02-19:00'}
```

The dates are formated as day/month-hour:minute.

The sorted list of dates would be `['01/02-19:00','01/02-21:00','01/03-22:00']`

And the wanted dict output `{'David':'01/02-19:00','Charles':'01/02-21:00','Martin':'01/03-22:00'}`

Comment: *"sort() won't work'* - Doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

- [[Python.Docs]: Built-in Functions - sorted(iterable, /, *, key=None, reverse=False)](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) to sort the dictionary items
- In order to properly compare the dates, each date string (value in the dictionary) needs to be converted to a *time.struct_time* object. That is done via [[Python.Docs]: time.strptime(string[, format])](https://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime)
- In the end, the sorted items are re-assembled into a *dict*

> ```
> >>> import time
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> d = {"Charles": "01/02-21:00", "Martin": "01/03-22:00", "David": "01/02-19:00"}
> >>>
> >>> dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda arg: time.strptime(arg[1], "%d/%m-%H:%M")))
> {'David': '01/02-19:00', 'Charles': '01/02-21:00', 'Martin': '01/03-22:00'}
> ```

As a generic piece of advice, try choosing for your identifiers names that aren't already used, as you will shadow previous definitions (in your case: [[Python.Docs]: Built-in Functions - class **dict**(**kwarg)](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#func-dict)).